# how to show that any monotone function defined on a measurable set is measurable?

Tags: functional-analysis, measurable-functions

Show that any monotone function defined on a measurable set $E\subseteq \Bbb R$ is measurable on $E$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/662099/show-that-if-e-subset-mathbbr-is-a-measurable-set-so-fe-rightarrow-mathb/662115#662115

Comment: Two things I want to mention for your kind information: This is not the standard way of asking questions here. One needs to show his/her effort. Otherwise, there is a high chance that the question will be closed within a few minutes. So please, next time onwards, show what you did. And the second thing is that please search here and there whether it is already asked or not. For example, I just googled the sentence and got the link. Thanks.

Comment: @SumantaDas I looked at your link, but in this example, the whole number line is considered, and not a measurable set on it

Comment: @SumantaDas I just don’t understand how to do this, and I can’t even come up with a solution, and I spent a lot of time on it, but I didn’t succeed, I thought on this site they help with problems in solving problems, but as a result, zero help

Comment: Then write what you did. Also, replace $\Bbb R$ with $E$ in the answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/662115/591889

Comment: Sumanta had provided you the link with the answer you need (with just one minor change), and you complaint about getting no help.....

Comment: @SumantaDas ok, I understand I will try to schedule my task

Comment: @ArcticChar I'm not complaining about anything, I just explained that there are no ideas how to solve, and the problem by reference has a completely different condition, the whole number line is considered there, and I consider an arbitrary subset of the number line, which is many times more difficult to do, and this task does not help in any way in solving the problem, but still thank you very much for your help